# default selected value in ng-repeat is always sent null to controller in select

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-options

I have below code, which successfully sets the default value selected but when without touching this dropdpwn, if value is sent to controller, it goes as null. but if i change the option value, value is passed to controller. what I am missing here?

```
 <select ng-model="detail.skuName"
            class="form-input-wrapper form-select-hidden">

        <option data-ng-repeat="sku in config.skuList" ng-selected="sku"
                >{{sku}}
        </option>

    </select>
```

config is an array of string. like

```
{"skuList":["abc", "xyz", "ghr"]}
```

Can you please help here

EDIT:
With sample code.

```
            'use strict';

            angular.module('TheSimpleApp', [
              'ui.router'
            ])
              .config(['$stateProvider',
                function($stateProvider) {

                  $stateProvider
                    .state('home', {
                      url: '/home',
                      views: {
                        'main': {
                          controller: 'HomeCtrl',
                          template: '<div>' +
                            '<h1>hello from parent</h1>' +
                            '<hr />' +
                            '<div ui-view="nameOtherThenSpace" ></div>' +
                            '<div>{{test}}</div>'+
                            '<select ng-model="detail.skuName" class="form-input-wrapper form-select-hidden">'+
                            '<option data-ng-repeat="sku in config.skuList" ng-selected="sku">{{sku}}'+
                            '</option>'+
                            '</select>'+
                            '<div>'+
                            '<a href="#" ng-click="send(detail)">send</a>',
                        }
                      }
                    })
                    .state('home.details', {
                      url: '/details',
                      views: {
                        "nameOtherThenSpace": {
                          template: "<h2>hello from a child</h3>",
                          controller: function($scope, $http, $state) {},
                        }
                      }
                    });
                }
              ])
              .controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope, $http, $state) {
                $scope.test = "Test Me";
                $scope.config = {"skuList":["abc", "xyz", "ghr"]};
                $scope.send = function(detail){
                  alert(angular.toJson(detail));

                }

              })

            .config([ '$urlRouterProvider',
              function($urlRouterProvider) {

                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
              }
            ]);
```

replace script.js at this plunker with the code above to visualize the issue, click on send without changing drop down value on load, undefined is passed, change drop down value, all good. I am looking the value to be correctly passed without changing the drop down value.

http://plnkr.co/edit/o91TgJXTcFVDFA9SUmSC?p=preview

Comment: How are you sending the value to the controller?

Comment: @Delta - i pass detail object in ng-click after click button <button ng-click="sendConfig(config)"> and in controller check for config.skuName. these fields are in a form

Comment: I am having a hard time following without the seeing the code that is setting your variable. However you might look into using ng-options instead of your ng-repeat

Comment: Try `ng-selected="selectedSku"`?

Comment: @Delta - post edited for your reference and my help :)

Comment: @Delta - tried with ng-options as well, but same issue. issue is only at load without changing drop down value, correct value should be passed at controller :(

Answer (score 0):

Can you check how you pass your data. find here sample with same data

[`sample`](http://plnkr.co/edit/o91TgJXTcFVDFA9SUmSC?p=preview)

Hope this help to resolve your issue.

Comment: issue still persists, what I am getting now. when u click on send without changing dropdown value, it is undefined but when u change, it gets correct value at controller. editing my post for changed code.

Comment: Hi, As per my understanding, this is happening because your model is not set (ng-model="detail.skuName") when it load. you can do that by initializing in controller ($scope.detail.skuName ="default"). when u chancing this got assigned.

Comment: How can I set it to default I. E.  Value of skulist? Using index? Can u help with that sample please?

Comment: Hi AngryJS, is it resolve your issue or still  you looking for other solution? let me know if this help.

Comment: No it didnt :( u have hardcoded the value, but i get it from controller

Comment: do you have any other solution please?

Comment: How you expecting? you can assigned through controller or the way i display. we can display through index but again your index value also hardcoded right?

Comment: No, my index value is not hardcoded, i get the data as shown in json above and when i display it on dropdown, one value should be selected and when sent to controller by clicking button, should be received in controller. nothing is hardcoded. How can i do it with index, by the way?

Comment: Hmm...you can use $index of ng-repeat. here is one [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/razh/NFNvc/) . hope this solve your problem